# How to set Background color and text color for unselected item in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, background, android-constraintlayout

I am using RecyclerView. Inside my RecyclerView item I am using one button view. Below is my RecyclerView item layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cost_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is my Adapter class,

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Plan> plans;
    private MyInterface myInterface;
    private int index=-1;
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Plan> planList, MyInterface myInterfaceListener) {
        this.plans =planList;
        this.myInterface=myInterfaceListener;
    }

   interface MyInterface{
        public void getId(String id);
   }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder=(MyViewHolder) holder;
        myViewHolder.costButton.setText(plans.get(position).getAmount());
        if(index==-1) {
            if(plans.get(0).getAmount().equalsIgnoreCase(plans.get(position).getAmount())) {
                myViewHolder.costButton.setBackgroundColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                myViewHolder.costButton.setTextColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
            }
            else{
                myViewHolder.costButton.setBackgroundColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
                myViewHolder.costButton.setTextColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            }
        }
        myViewHolder.costButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                index=position;
                if(index==position){
                    myViewHolder.costButton.setBackgroundColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                    myViewHolder.costButton.setTextColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
                }
                else{
                    myViewHolder.costButton.setBackgroundColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
                    myViewHolder.costButton.setTextColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return plans.size();
    }

    private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private Button costButton;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            costButton=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cost_button);

        }
    }

}
```

I am able to set background color and text color for selected item. My Problem is, consider there is 4 buttons. If I click button 1, then I am able to change color. After that I am clicking button 2. In this time color changes for clicked item and also already changed color for button 1  remain same. This is my problem. Anybody help me with this.

Comment: please post the code snippet in `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: @HaiHack added my RecyclerView Adapter class. Kindly check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code snippet to this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder=(MyViewHolder) holder;
        myViewHolder.costButton.setText(plans.get(position).getAmount());
        if(index==-1) {
            if(plans.get(0).getAmount().equalsIgnoreCase(plans.get(position).getAmount())) {
                myViewHolder.costButton.setBackgroundColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                myViewHolder.costButton.setTextColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
            }
            else{
                myViewHolder.costButton.setBackgroundColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
                myViewHolder.costButton.setTextColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            }
        }else{
            if(index==position){
                myViewHolder.costButton.setBackgroundColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                myViewHolder.costButton.setTextColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
            }
            else{
                myViewHolder.costButton.setBackgroundColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
                myViewHolder.costButton.setTextColor(myViewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            }
        }
        myViewHolder.costButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                index=position;
               notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Remember that do not use ConstraintLayout in RecyclerView as it is bad for the performance according to this article https://blog.usejournal.com/improve-recyclerview-performance-ede5cec6c5bf

Answer (score 0):

you can use checkbox instead of button and customize it according to your need.

Comment: No. I only need to use button.